# Stale session stores with webapp2 in GAE for Python

Tags: google-app-engine, session, webapp2, google-app-engine-python

I have a GAE Python app that stores session data in a SessionStore object obtained via `webapp2_extras.sessions.get_store(request=self.request)`.

I have seen sessions persist for days when I don't shut my browser down, but it occurs to me that as admin for the app, I have no way of clearing stale SessionStore objects in the server, that is, when a user's data that will never be accessed again after his or her browser is closed.

Is this a memory leak in my app running on GAE, or does GAE or WEBAPP2 have some strategy for recognizing a stale session and releasing that memory? I can't find an answer in the GAE/WEBAPP2 docs, so if you have a link that provides the answer, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the expiration time of a session store with [webapp2_extras.sessions.default_config](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html):

> **session_max_age**: Default session expiration time in seconds.
>   Limits the duration of the contents of a cookie, even if a session
>   cookie exists. If None, the contents lasts as long as the cookie is
>   valid. Default is None.

Now if you want to handle the expiration yourself,
a strategy for recognizing a stale session might be to store a timestamp in the cookie or the session data and to check it on each page request.  When you want to expire the session, call [self.session.clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025612/gae-webapp2-destroying-session-doesnt-work/12026815#12026815).

Comment: Sorry for my down-vote, Brent. My initial reading was that this only sets the cookie's expiration, especially given your strategy suggestion, which I don't believe works, since the app may never get a chance to call clear(). But upon re-reading, it appears that the parameter you list does indeed set a session time-out in the server, so that addresses my original requirement even though the strategy comment doesn't seem to. Unfortunately, I used the wrong vote and can't change it unless you make some edit to your answer. Thanks for your help, and sorry again.

Comment: I clarified the strategy option